# MSSQL trigger will not work with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

My code is to have a trigger that recognize when a job failed, sends an email and update our ticketing system using a stored procedure that is in a linked db.

The emailing part works perfect, but when adding the ticket procedure code the email wont send, the ticket will not open, and the specific line that was supposed to be in msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory is actually missing, like the insert failed or the line was deleted.

The procedure code line by itself works fine, and if i run the same code without the trigger part it also works fine.

The code works ok outside of the trigger, which makes me think I missing something regarding the way triggers work.

```
    alter TRIGGER trig_open_ticket_failed
ON msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
after INSERT
AS begin
 DECLARE @MaxInstance int
Declare @failedFlag int
Declare @JobName varchar(50)
Declare @ErrorInfo varchar(max)
Declare @stepName varchar(50)
set @MaxInstance= (select MAX(instance_id) 
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    )



 select top 1 @failedFlag = hs.run_status, @stepName=hs.step_name
 from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory hs join msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
 on hs.job_id=sj.job_id
 where instance_id= @MaxInstance

 if @failedFlag=0 
 BEGIN


SELECT TOP 1 @JobName= 'LKSQL job failed:' + SJ.name, @ErrorInfo=hs.message
 from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory hs join msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
on hs.job_id=sj.job_id
where instance_id= @MaxInstance 
set @errorInfo= 'Job: '+ @JobName +' Failed with error: '+ @errorInfo;


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'name',
@recipients = 'adrs@email.com',
@body = @ErrorInfo,
@subject = @JobName ;




exec [mainsql01].[SlickTicket].[dbo].[AddTicket] 'servicesFailed',@jobName, @ErrorInfo,    '5','4' ;

END
 end
GO
```

Thank you,
Idan.

Comment: why doesn't it use the INSERTED trigger table?

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then please add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement.  (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 0):

your trigger will be executing as caller by default,which I am guessing does not have permission to use your addticket procedure. try adding

```
 execute as user_name
```

where user_name has permission to use that proc